# How to embed tab character in string to change the form field

Tags: c#

i have a form with two fields(called firstname and secondname) and a qr code which returns string(like Eliza Smith).A scanner is used to enter the data. what i want is to put tab charecter between Eliza and Smith. so that smith can be fillup in the second field automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tab character the same way you use any other character.
You can also use its escape code, `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on what your asking? Are you asking that the value of the firstname and secondname variables are placed into another field\variable with a tab in the middle. If so then this should do it.

```
string s = firstname + "\t" + secondname;
```

Comment: Can I also direct you to www.google.com?  As a developer, I've found that google and the msdn library are my best resources for information.  Especially when it comes to common questions.

Comment: hllo zeencat, after using "\t" it takes the space on same field

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand.  Could you provide an example please?

Comment: I've just quickly tried it and a tab does appear between firstname and second name.  Sample code below.                              string s = tbFirstName.Text + "\t" + tbSecond.Text;
tbFullName.Text = s;